# pip install не работает. через командную строку выдает fatal error, python

Tags: python, pip

[image: 2]

[image: 1]

просмотрел большинство решений через сайты, не помогают. через командную строку и обычный пробовал, не получается. проверил - пип установлен на питон.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Comment: Обнови pip, setuptools, cmake, wheel.

Comment: @Глеб а каким образом, `pip`-то не работает.

Comment: Гхм, действительно. Но pip можно обновить и "снаружи".

Comment: @Глеб как? не знаю просто. типо файлы скачать с инета, а потом в проводнике копатся?

Comment: @chaynik228, а какие проблемы? Это не сложно вроде, десять раз тыкнуть мышкой.

Comment: Попробуйте вот отсюда советы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using Но проще всего похоже переставить питон из нормального официального инсталлятора. Ну или для начала попробуйте `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @CrazyElf python -m pip install --upgrade pip не работает, а так я уже читал тот гайд. не помогло

Comment: снести все, что касается python  и его самого, почистить реестр и после этого поставить заново python

Comment: @Volk есть ли проги для этого? копатся в реестре долго просто.

Comment: CCleaner -нормальная чистка реестра. Как вариант.